# Seeking line by line git blame extension for Visual Studio (NOT VS Code)

Tags: git, visual-studio

I was just issued a new company laptop and have lost all of my VS extensions. I had one that did line by line `git blame`, so that I could see who had added a line of code six months ago and go ask him why.

I can't find it again in the marketplace.  Any ideas? Please note, that I use Visual Studio, and not Visual Studio Code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076311/how-to-show-git-blame-in-visual-studio-2013 - afaik the functionality is available out of the box in VS. No extensions needed.
Just Right-click -> Git -> Blame (Annotate) I think.
[image: Screenshot of right clicking in a file in VS Enterprise]

Comment: D'oh!!!!! How could I have overlooked that?